# Why does adding a prototype lead to non-equality of constructors

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

Just when I think I understand js objects they throw something new at me.

In this code (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8Eng/1/)

```
var impl = function () {
        var P = function () {};
        P.prototype = {};
        return P;
    },
    P = impl();
    p = new P();

console.log(p.constructor === P);
```

checking for equality on the constructor returns false when I add a prototype, but if you remove the line that adds the prototype then it returns true. Extending the prototype via `P.prototype.prop = 'prop'` preserves equality too. `p instanceof P` always returns true.

Can someone please explain the intricacies of why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects created in your code (via `new` or literals like `{}`) do not have a "constructor" property, therefore when you write `p.construtor`, it's resolved via the prototype chain, that is, `p.__proto__` is looked for, then, `p.__proto__.__proto__` etc.

Since you set `P.prototype` to an empty object, the first call fails (`p.__proto__`, aka `P.prototype`, aka `{}` has no `constructor`), so the engine looks in `{}.__proto__`, which is `Object.prototype` and finds `constructor` there. Of course, this one has nothing to do with P, it's just the default Object constructor.

Note that `instanceof` doesn't use constructors, `x instanceof F` is interpreted as `x.__proto__ == F.prototype or x.__proto__.__proto__ == F.prototype` etc

Answer (score 2):

```
    P.prototype = {};
```

This does not only change the prototype, it also sets the constructor to `Object`. And `Object` is definitely not identical to `P`.

If you want that the equality holds, set the `constructor` property after re-assigning the `prototype`:

```
var P = function () {};
P.prototype = {};
P.prototype.constructor = P;
return P;
```

Comment: strictly speaking `P.prototype` does not "set" a constructor, it just changes the proto chain.

Answer (score 0):

"Object" class is the prototype of every object in JS and `constructor` is a property of Object class. So if you reassign the `prototype` property of any object to something else, the `constructor` property which belongs to Object class is also lost. But if you add any new property to the prototype of an object, the constructor is not lost.